# how do Value Types in .NET actually work?

Tags: c#

I have a problem with understanding Value Types representation in .NET.
Each Value Type is derived from System.ValueType class, so does this mean that Value Type is a class?

For example, if i write:

```
int x = 5;
```

it means that i create an instance of `System.Int32` class an' write it into variable x??

Comment: [System.ValueType](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.valuetype.aspx)

Comment: _derived from System.ValueType class_ This is a special form of deriving, not the same as inheritance. It's built into the Fx.

Comment: For future readers: [**The Truth About Value Types**](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/ericlippert/archive/2010/09/30/the-truth-about-value-types.aspx)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The System.ValueType class is really just a "meta" class, and internally is handled differently than normal classes. Structs and primitive types inherit System.ValueType implicitly, but that type doesn't actually exist during runtime, it's just a way for assemblies to mark that a class should be treated like a value type struct and take on pass-by-value semantics.

Contrary to the other answers, value types are not always allocated on the stack. When they are fields in a class, they sit on the heap just like the rest of the class data when that object is instantiated. Local variables can also be hoisted into an implicit class when used inside iterators or closures.

Answer (score 1):

See [Eric Lippert's article](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/ericlippert/archive/2009/04/27/the-stack-is-an-implementation-detail.aspx).

In short, a value type is copied by value. Value types are classes just like reference types, and instances of value types are objects. `5` is an object, an instance of `System.Int32` (`int` for short).

Answer (score 0):

Now, there's a lot to talk about that. Seriously, there's like hundred of pages about this topic on the net, and most of it burns my cerebral matter at an alarming rate.

What I actually remembered is, int and Int32 is the same thing, and both act like a struct, not a class. "int" being a shortcut to Int32. (If you put your mouse over a int, the tooltip reads "struct System.Int32".
Which means:

```
public class BoxedInt
{
    public int x;

    public BoxedInt(int i) { x = i; }
}

public Test()
{
    BoxedInt bi = new BoxedInt(10);
    Boxed(bi);
    Console.WriteLine(bi.x); // Returns 11, as any reference type would.

    int vi = 10;
    Valued(vi);
    Console.WriteLine(vi); // Returns 10, because it acts like a struct. (Which it is)
}

public void Boxed(BoxedInt i)
{
    i.x++;
}

public void Valued(int i)
{
    i++;
}
```

Comment: `public void Valued(ref int i)` will return 11, because ... ?

Comment: Boxed returns 11, Valued returns 10.

Comment: A boxed value, or if you prefer, a value contained inside a class is like being inside a box. If I tell you where the box exist and you change its content, I can check the box and see what change you've done. For this, the class act as a box, and it will exist as long as somewhere in the code reference it. As for a normal value, I can tell you that value but I cannot give you it. If you decide that it should change, I have no way to know that unless you explicitly tell me. For this, the "i" only exist within the bounderies of the Valued method and is destroyed as soon as the method is done.

Comment: So, `(` **`ref`** `int i)` will return 11, because?

Comment: Because the "ref" keyword allow you to pass it by reference... The same way as if you were boxing it inside a reference type (class). I manually boxed it in a class in the example to show that.

Comment: Which you should also indicate to. By the way there is no actual boxing when passing ValueType by `ref`.

Answer (score -2):

Value Types are not classes. These are builtin types in languages and are handled by .NET CTS (Common Type System). CTS is a component inside CLR which is responsible for handling the value types such as bool, int, double, float etc. 
When you create an object of value type then it is created on stack. When you pass it to a function or return from a function then a new object is created for it in ram. But in case of reference types, only reference of object is passed and new object is not created inm memory.
There are some userdefined value types which are not in language specification and are defined by users. Such value types are inherited from System.ValueType.
Example of such valuetype is Complex number. We can make our own userdefined type of complex numbers using System.ValueType.

Comment: I am not going to downvote since this is your first day on SO, but please read the comments of other answer

Comment: I am going to downvote since it's wrong. See http://blogs.msdn.com/b/ericlippert/archive/2009/04/27/the-stack-is-an-implementation-detail.aspx for a thorough treatment of value types.

Comment: @ThomSmith: Although the stack is an implementation detail, the fundamental point is correct: value-type storage locations (including compiler temporaries) do not hold class objects.  The C# spec might claim that the contents of an `Int32` field inherit from `System.Object`, but the CLI spec (which describes how the world of managed code actually works) makes clear that `System.Int32` describes two types: a heap-object type which derives from `System.Object` and a storage-location type which isn't an object.  The C# spec may pretend otherwise, but that doesn't make it true.

Comment: The C# spec does not "pretend" otherwise – it *defines* otherwise, and that does make it true. In C#, an Int32 is an object. The implementation details in the CLI spec are CLI implementation details.